# How to make icon with picture from assets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make an icon but with imported pic
This is my code but doesn't work

```
IconButton(icon: isDonated ? AssetImage('assets/donate.png') : AssetImage('assets/donated.png'), onPressed: null)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is `assets/donate.png` declared in your `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Image.asset` instead of `AssetImage`

```html
      Image.asset( 
                  imageName,
                  height: 20,
                  width: 20,
                ),
```

And if you want clickable icon then please wrap this `Image.asset` with `Gesturedetector` widget.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `ImageIcon`

```
ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/youricon.png"), color: Colors.yourColor, size: yourSize,),
```